# Angular-ui bootstrap- how to display selected input value in a modal?

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new in angular.js. I have to display in a modal the selected value of input, but I don't succeed.
I have the following inputs:

```
   <form>
      <input type="radio" name="toggleDiv" value="show" ng-click="show()"   checked/> Show Text
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="toggleDiv" ng-click="hide()" value="hide"/> Hide Text
            </form>
```

I have to open a popup dialog and display the value of the selected value.
The moodal:

```
  <div class="row" ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
                <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        {{ inputsVal }}
                    </div>
                </script>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
        </div>
```

I try the following function:

```
    app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal) {
  $scope.open = function () {
           $scope.inputsValue=$('input:checked').val()
           return $scope.inputsValue
}}
    }
```

Comment: @charlietfl- the inputsValue is no displayed in the modal

Answer (score 0):

your implementation is wrong.check anguar ui bootstrap modal [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

You have to do like this

```
$scope.open = function () {
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.myForm;
    }
  }
});
```

in your controller,

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

in html,

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        {{ items.input}}
                    </div>
                </script>
<form>
      <input type="radio" name="toggleDiv" ng-model="myForm.input" value="show" ng-click="show()"   checked/> Show Text
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="toggleDiv" ng-click="hide()" value="hide"/> Hide Text
            </form>
```

**edit**

If you want to work with jquery way then you need to use $apply()

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
             $scope.inputsValue=$('input:checked').val();
        });
```

hope this helps .. :)